# AWS EKS logging to CloudWatch - how to send logs only, without metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I would like to forward the logs of select services running on my EKS cluster to CloudWatch for cluster-independent storage and better observability.

Following the quickstart outlined at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-EKS-quickstart.html I've managed to get the logs forwarded via Fluent Bit service, but that has also generated 170 Container Insights metrics channels. Not only are those metrics not required, but they also appear to cost a fair bit.

How can I disable the collection of cluster metrics such as cpu / memory / network / etc, and only keep forwarding container logs to CloudWatch? I'm having a very hard time finding any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out - the `cloudwatch-agent` daemonset from quickstart guide is what's sending the metrics, but it's not required for log forwarding. All the objects with names related to `cloudwatch-agent` in quickstart `yaml` file are not required for log forwarding.

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit? Are you getting the log's forwarded frequently? How did you change the configuration or startup?

Comment: @Ernesto Not sure what to expand there - I just deleted every resource with name related to `cloudwatch-agent` from the amazon quickstart yaml before applying it. That achieved my goal of getting only the logs, and not the CPU/RAM metrics. And the logs seem to appear in Cloudwatch in "real time", that is moments after the action that causes the log write. Good enough for the use case of "inspect logs later on", but I haven't measured the exact speed.

Comment: The edit queue on this answer is full, so I am commenting and writing a second answer, but credit to Toms since he found it. To stop metric creation you need to delete the entire object named `metrics` in the JSON or YAML configuration file

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Toms Mikoss, you need to delete the `metrics` object in your configuration file. This file is the one that you pass to the agent when starting

This applies to "on-premises" "linux" installations. I havent tested this on windows, nor EC2 but I imagine it will be similar. The [AWS Documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-premise.html) says that you can also distribute the configuration via SSM, but again, I imagine the answer here is still applicable.

Example of file with metrics:

```json
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/var/log/nginx.log",
                        "log_group_name": "nginx",
                        "log_stream_name": "{hostname}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "metrics_collected": {
            "cpu": {
                "measurement": [
                    "cpu_usage_idle",
                    "cpu_usage_iowait"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "totalcpu": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of file without metrics:

```json
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/var/log/nginx.log",
                        "log_group_name": "nginx",
                        "log_stream_name": "{hostname}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, the command to start for linux on-premises servers:

```bash
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config \
 -m onPremise -s -c file:configuration-file-path
```

More details in the [AWS Documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-premise.html)